# Jquery Cool Drag and Drop snap to position

Tags: jquery

Anyone know how you do that cool thing in JQuery where you can drag and drop divs and it snaps to position and saves location?

Comment: @Lorenzo - I think you need to stop caring about how other people use the site so much

Comment: @Charles Boyung: Some people just dont read the FAQ and completely ignore how to use a site like this. I am happy that after the comment some of them started to use it better like LooDaFunk. But, apart from this, what is your comment meaning?

Comment: @Lorenzo - you had four straight comments telling people the exact same thing and a fifth not to much before that. If people don't want to vote things up, why is that your problem to enforce?

Comment: @Lorenzo - oh, and if you expect people to read a FAQ, then you clearly know nothing about users in general. People are not going to go and start reading FAQs on every site they visit. In fact, the only time that is likely on this site specifically is when they disagree with how someone else is doing things.

Comment: @Charles - have you read the FAQ? Be nice ;)

Comment: @st3 - what's not nice? I'm helping him out by telling him something he clearly didn't already know. Isn't that why we're here? To educate people? :)

Comment: @Charles Boyung: To educate other people you need to be educate yourself. best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try checking out [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/home) - more relevantly the [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#snap-to) feature.

Answer (score 6):

[This tutorial](http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/) suits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [DropThings](http://dropthings.omaralzabir.com/).

This is an open source project available at [Codeplex](http://dropthings.codeplex.com/) that could be a good source of information for your requirement

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [interactjs](http://interactjs.io/) with a great support for touch events